# Adding a library into Flex 4 (flex iframe)

Tags: iframe, actionscript, flex4, adobe, flash-builder

I am trying to use flex iframe with an Adobe Flex project in Flash Builder, and I've added the library through `Project -> Properties -> Library Path -> Add SWC Folder` but I am still getting the error `The prefix "flexiframe" for element "flexiframe:IFrame" is not bound`, as if I haven't linked it.

```
<flexiframe:IFrame id="googleIFrame"
                       label="Google"
                       source="htp://google.com"
                       width="80%"
                       height="80%"/>
```

I am extremely new to Flex, and I cannot find any good resources on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing the namespace definition on top of your file:

> ```
> <s:Application xmlns:fx=“http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009”
>                xmlns:s=“library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark”
>                xmlns:mx=“library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx”
>                xmlns:flexiframe="http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/">
> [...]
>
> </s:Application>
> ```

You can see this in the [user's guide](https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe/wiki/Users-guide).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting: `Could not resolve <flexiframe:IFrame> to a component implementation`

Comment: You should download the `swc` version of the library from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.code.flex-iframe%22%20AND%20a%3A%22flex-iframe%22). Then, follow these [instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fe6.html#WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7f7a) to add it to your project. Bear in mind that you want to use `add SWC` NOT `add SWC folder`...

Answer (score 0):

First download SWC folder from http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/downloads/list.
Then set this Project->Properties->Flex Build Path->Add SWC.
Link .swc from build folder. Include this also  xmlns:flexiframe="http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/"